Enable Drive and Docs on Google Drive Labels API
The Google Drive Labels API gives the possibility to create, modify and publish a label, but those are useless unless you check the "Drive and Docs" option. Which seems to be impossible via the API, is there a known way to do it ?
This page is accessible here
Is there any workaround ?
I tried to

change the labels copy mode

to publish the label again

Get the labels data after checking the option to see the results in the response, nothing changed, si I guess it's not an option you can currently manage with the API ?



After some testing on a Google Workspace account, the Drive Labels API doesn't support automatically activating created labels for Drive and Docs in Classification labels. Moreover, as per Get started as a Drive labels admin:

You can use the Labels API to create, edit, apply, and remove labels programmatically. For details, see the Google Drive Labels API documentation.

Highlighting the word create, the API should be able to activate the settings. However, it seems that the only option for doing so is through the Admin console.
What I would recommend is to submit a bug report to let Google know about the unusual behavior that's going on.

Thanks for your feedback ! I will submit a bug report as you recommend and will probably update this post once I have an answer.
